# What is the most efficient way to convert list of structs to dictionary?

Tags: c#

I have a struct that consists of multiple type elements as follows:

```cs
public struct mystruct 
{  
        int key;
        string value;  
}
```

What is the most efficient way to convert list of this struct to a dictionary that its keys are `mystruct.key` and values are list of `mystruct.value`?

i implement it as follows

```cs
Dictionary<int, List<string>> mydictionary = new Dictionary<int, List<string>>();
foreach (var item in mystruct_list)
            {
                if (!mydictionary.ContainsKey(item.key))
                    mydictionary.Add(item.key, new List<string>());
                mydictionary[item.key].Add(item.value);
            }
```

Comment: How do the values of `value` look like? You want to split them, right?

Comment: The most efficient way is not at all, because it'll eat up a lot more memory that way. Given this, the right question is probably [why do you care about *most* efficient](https://ericlippert.com/2012/12/17/performance-rant/) -- what's your *actual* scenario?

Comment: no i don't want to split them. they are some words and its can be list of words for one key.

Comment: Have you tried to do this and found your method was insufficiently efficient? Please show what you've tried, and what about it you deemed "inefficient".

Comment: @JeroenMostert I have a list of 2 million keys and almost 20 values for each key. my computer doesnt respond in proper time by using for loops. i need some low level instructions to do this job sth like linq approaches or so.

Comment: Linq can be slower than for loops - it may be helpful if you can show what you have tried so far.

Comment: thanks, you'r right. @Rango

Comment: So where are the 2 million keys coming from? Are you reading all of them first and then converting them into a dictionary, or can the dictionary be built on the fly? You cannot get lower level than a `for` loop (LINQ is actually very high level), but you can certainly optimize either getting the values, or optimize the allocation (by properly setting the capacity first).

Comment: Are these key/value pairs stored in a database? Maybe you need to add appropriate indexes and query that db for the keys/values you *really* need.

Comment: Use `TryGetValue` on the dictionary rather looking for the key twice (`ContainsKey()` and then the `dictionary[key]` lookup), you will save a *lot* of unnecessary key lookups.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that there is collection of mystruct objects and key and value fields are public you can use code below:

```
List<mystruct> myElements ... //just declaration
var result = myElements
    .GroupBy(c => c.key)
    .ToDictionary(
         c => c.Key,
         c => c.Select(i => i.value).ToList());
```

Comment: Yes, I guess you're right. It seems I just read "efficient" as shortest code. Do you think I should remove this answer as it doesn't answer question?

Answer (score 0):

If you relax the requirement to have a `IEnumerable<string>` instead of a `IList<string>` as the values, the lookup is the thing you are looking for (internally it is materialized, so no worries about enumerating multiple times).

```
IEnumerable<mystruct> source = // ...

var lookup = x.ToLookup(c => c.key, c => c.value);
foreach (var g in lookup)
    Console.WriteLine($"Key: {g.Key}, Values: {string.Join(", ", g)}");
```

The nice thing about lookups is that they support, well, lookup

```
var group3 = lookup[3];
```

, and that this will give you an empty sequence when accessed with a non-existent key, instead of throwing a `KeyNotFoundException` at you.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the assumption of having 2 million keys and 20 values per key, already in memory, this is how I would do it:

```cs
var d = new Dictionary<int, List<string>>();
foreach (var s in mystruct_list)
{
    if (!d.TryGetValue(s.key, out List<string> list))
    {
        list = new List<string>();
        d[s.key] = list;
    }
    list.Add(s.value);
}
```

This should result in 42 million dictionary index reads: 40 million (20 * 2 million) for `TryGetValue`, plus 2 million index reads when first storing the list.

Your version does 82 million index reads: for every one of the 20 * 2 million values, it calls both `ContainsKey()` and `mydictionary[item.key]`, so that's 20 * 2 * 2 million, plus another 2 million to add the list.

(The code should be more or less correct, been a long time since I've written c#)